# Select android library version at runtime

Tags: android, classloader, android-library

I'm working on an Android application which communicate with different API versions. To clearify that, let's look at the following example:

Company A has API version 1.0.0
Company B has API version 1.1.0
Company C has API version 1.1.2

Our android application use a generated .jar version 1.1.2. The .jar contains model classes which represent a message used for communicate between frontend and backend. Most of them are similar except the newer one has more attributes than the older one.

The problem is user can select to connect either A, B, or C. If the user select A or B, the application will stop because backend API is not compatible with what we implemented.

I have been search through the internet and haven't found any solution for this. Is it possible to create a wrapper which reference to the correct version of library at runtime?

Comment: Most likely, you cannot have more than one copy of the library in your app at once, as the classes will have the same classes with the same fully-qualified class names. If you have control over the process for "use a generated .jar", perhaps you can arrange for the three versions to be placed into three Java packages, and have your code use classes from the appropriate package based on user selection.

Comment: @CommonsWare It seem difficult to implment. I have studied further and found some concept which is interested. It's called "Dynamic library". I wonder is it possible to build a dynamic library which wrap over multiple static libraries?